# Best way assigning story to location in a game?

Tags: python, coordinate, adventure

I have a simple question.
Here is my story game so far:

```
x = 0
y = 0
coords = (x,y)
def move(player) :
while 1 :
    global x
    global y
    global coords
    user_in = raw_input()
    if user_in == "w":
        y += 1
    elif user_in == "d":
        x += 1
    elif user_in == "a":
        x -= 1
    elif user_in == "s":
        y -= 1
    else :
        print "Thats not an assigned key"
    coords = (x,y)
    print player, "moved to", coords

move("Mason")
```

I know that I could make an if statement for each set of coordinates, but I'm feeling pythonic, and I would like to find a fast and efficient way to do this. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: a dictionary of (x,y) keys and story elements?

Comment: Thank you! I did not think of that. What about adding an inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @isedev said in a comment, I recommend using a dictionary that maps location tuples to data about what is found in that location.

I would make a class called `Room` or `Area` that defines what exists at that location.  Then make a dictionary called `world` or something that maps all the locations a player can go.  If there is no `Area` object at a given location, then it is impossible to go there (maybe it's impassible forest, solid rock, or whatever makes sense in your game).

I suggest you read through a tutorial on how to write an adventure game in Python.  The book *Learn Python the Hard Way* has a chapter devoted to this, and you can get that book for free on the Internet:

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

It might make more sense if you read through the whole book in order.

If you don't like that one, try a Google search for "adventure game tutorial Python" and you will find others.

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: If I could up vote you I would! (I know I'm not supposed to comment things like that :P)